# How to format 'node reference' field values from the Views module

Tags: 7, views, forms, nodes

How can I format the output of a 'node reference' field that is generated using a View?

Currently it's formatted as (See 2nd graphic): **"FirstName - Lastname Pagetitle"**

I'm trying to change that to: **"Firstname Lastname"**

Where do I modify this fields format?

Here is my current view:

[image]

Here is the 'node reference' output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. Initially it would appear that the "Pagetitle" is being stored in the Last Name field. However assuming that it's not, you can use the [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to find out what and where is theming that field's output. The culpript could very likely be inside one of your own custom Views templates or theme function override. If not, devel_themer should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for this.  devel_themer is an incredible tool!  You absolutely nailed the issue as well. :)  Thank you!